# combinatorics problem: find all possible ordered permutations in a tuple

Tags: combinatorics

I have a tuple that looks like this:

$(1,2,3,4)$

I want to generate all possible nested tuples that can be made from the original tuple which maintain the original order of the array. For the example above, I'm looking for:

$((1,2,3,4))$
$((1),(2,3,4))$
$((1),(2),(3,4))$
$((1,2,3),(4))$
$((1,2),(3,4))$
$((1),(2,3),(4))$
...

I'm not sure what to call this in combinatorics? It seems similar to a permutation, but I do not want certain permutations that are out of order like:

$((1, 3),(2,4))$

Can anyone explain how I can find this subset of permutations where order is maintained?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost done, there are only two more not on your list, namely,

$((1),(2),(3),(4))$
$((1,2),(3),(4))$

Why is that all of them? Every one of your objects looks like this:
$$
((1 \,\_\, 2 \,\_\, 3 \,\_\, 4))
$$
where each _ is filled with either a 
$$
,\qquad \text{or a} \qquad),(
$$
Since there are 3 blanks, and two choices for each black, there are $2^3=8$ objects in total.

Comment: Is it possible to claim that, given a $n$-elements tuple, the number of objects that one can obtain given the rules stated by the OP is $2^{n-1}$?

Comment: @uomoinverde That is true